# Generar un array de objetos a traves de un metodo computado en vueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hola a todos en esta ocasión acudo a ustedes por lo siguiente, quiero crear un objeto en JS con datos que me llegan de un array, el array contiene los siguientes datos:

```
const columnsTable = [
  "id",
  "nombre",
  "edad"
];
```

El array de odjetos que quiero crear con el array anterior, tiene que tener la siguiente estructura:

```
 columns: [
        {
          name: 'id', align: 'center', label: 'id', field: 'id'
        },
        {
          name: 'nombre', align: 'center', label: 'nombre', field: 'nombre'
        },
        {
          name: 'edad', align: 'center', label: 'edad', field: 'edad'
        }
      ]
    }
```

Donde cada objeto representado en el array de objetos tiene un valor del array columsTable en name, label y field.
[![Mi metodo computado es el siguiente][1]][1]
[![Me retorna lo siguiente][2]][2]
Siguiendo la respuesta de vicent el meotdo computado ha qudado de la siguiente manera:

```
computed: {
    columsActive() {
      let obj;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.columnsTable.length; i += 1) {
        obj = {};
        obj.name = this.columnsTable[i];
        obj.align = 'center';
        obj.label = this.columnsTable[i];
        obj.field = this.columnsTable[i];
        // eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties
        this.colums.push(obj)
      }
      return this.colums
}
  }
```

El resultado del metodo computado es el siguiente:

```
0:Object
align:"center"
field:Array[6]
0:"id"
1:"nombre"
2:"edad"
3:"estado_civil"
4:"created_at"
5:"updated_at"
label:Array[6]
0:"id"
1:"nombre"
2:"edad"
3:"estado_civil"
4:"created_at"
5:"updated_at"
name:Array[6]
0:"id"
1:"nombre"
2:"edad"
3:"estado_civil"
4:"created_at"
5:"updated_at"
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario en seguida añado el codigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes construir el array de objetos de la siguiente forma:

```js
const columnsTable = ["id","nombre","edad"];

let columns = [];
let obj;
for (let i = 0;i<columnsTable.length;i++){
    obj = {};
    obj.name = columnsTable[i];
    obj.align = 'center';
    obj.label = columnsTable[i];
    obj.field = columnsTable[i];
    
    columns.push(obj);
}

console.log(columns);
```

Si quieres incorporarlo al computed de VUE, debes recoger como parámetro columnsTable y hacer el return de la variable columns construida en el método.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta he intentado tal y como me indicas y me ha saltado el mismo resultado del problema, actualizo la pregunta con los resultados obtenidos.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer esto es lo que querías conseguir. La forma en la que encontré solución a lo que necesitabas, es esto.

**Ejemplo:**

```js
var array = [
  ["id", "nombre", "edad"],
  ["id", "nombre", "edad"]
];
array.push(["12", "Carlos", "24"]);
var colums = [];

array.forEach((key, i) => {
  colums.push({
    name: key[0],
    aling: "center",
    label: key[1],
    field: key[2]
  });
});

console.log(colums)
```

Espero haberte ayudado!